# How to archive an entire FTP server where many of the filenames seem to include illegal characters

Tags: ftp, wget, mirroring

I am trying to use `wget -m <address>` to download the contents of an FTP server. A lot of the content is icelandic and so contains a bunch of weird characters that I think are causing issues as I keep seeing:

```
Incomplete or invalid multibyte sequence encountered
```

I have tried adding flags such as `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol` but to no avail.

I have also tried using `lftp` but doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`wget` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

> If you specify `‘nocontrol’`, then the escaping of the control
> characters is also switched off.

that is it as actually more permissive than default, *bunch of weird characters* suggest you have some issues with getting encoding right and therefore `ascii` seems to be best fit for your use case

> The `‘ascii’` mode is used to specify that any bytes whose values are
> outside the range of ASCII characters (that is, greater than 127)
> shall be escaped. This can be useful when saving filenames whose
> encoding does not match the one used locally.

As I do not have ability to test, please try it and write about result it give.

Comment: This works. It replaces the icelandic characters with a sequence of numbers and escape characters / `%` characters, this is fine for my use case but worth noting for others